# Unable to scroll MaterializeCSS sidenav list to the bottom

Tags: html, jquery, css, materialize

I'm working on this site that will use the materialize css framework. I've built out some of it already but keep running into problems with the sidenavs. I've worked out most of the problems but I still am unable to scroll to the end of the sidenav list. I'm have added some custom styles but I don't think that is interfering with it. Not really sure what is wrong. Run the code and try scrolling the left sidenav all the way to the bottom. It stops scrolling offscreen somewhere and the last list element never becomes visible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- Website Title -->
  <title>The Demo</title>
  <!-- Custom styles -->
  <style>
    /* Custom navbar shadow */
    
    .navbar-fixed {
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    /* Custom sizing and shadow for sidenav */
    
    .custom-sidenav {
      top: 64px;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .custom-sidenav {
        top: 0;
      }
      .navbar-fixed {
        z-index: 997;
      }
    }
    /* Custom sizing for container to fit sidenav */
    
    .custom-content-container {
      padding-left: 157px;
      padding-right: 157px;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
      .custom-content-container {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- NavBar -->
  <header class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">The Demo</a>
        <a href="#" data-target="sidenav-1" class="sidenav-trigger show-on-large brand-logo left"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <a href="#" data-target="sidenav-2" class="sidenav-trigger show-on-large brand-logo right"><i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Menu -->
  <aside id="sidenav-1" class="sidenav sidenav-fixed custom-sidenav">
    <ul>
      <li class="center">
        <h5>Menu</h5>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
      <li>
        <div class="divider"></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="btn">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <!-- Shopping Cart -->
  <aside id="sidenav-2" class="sidenav sidenav-fixed custom-sidenav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery Inline-->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.sidenav').sidenav();
      $('#sidenav-1').sidenav({
        edge: 'left'
      });
      $('#sidenav-2').sidenav({
        edge: 'right'
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.custom-sidenav {
  top: 64px;
}
```

I know my answer is late, but anyway. This style moves the entire sidenav down. To fix that you need to add height. So it should be:

```
.custom-sidenav {
  top: 64px;
  height: 100%;
}
```